# Extend DIVs inside a div wrapper - fixed layout

Tags: html, css

I want to know how can I extend every DIVs inside a div wrapper. My `div` wrapper is fixed and has a width of `980px`.

My HTML goes here:

```
    <div id="wrapper" >

        <div id="header" >
            <strong>HEADER</strong>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <strong>Navigation</strong>
        </nav>

        <div id="content" >
            <div class="sidebar" >
                <p>sidebar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content" >
                <p>content goes here.....</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <strong>copyright etc....</strong>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ognceoaL/1/)

What I want to achieve is every DIVs which has`background-color` will expand and max-out the width of wrapper or something like filling the width of body to the fullest. But the content or texts must still has the width of `980px` and is fixed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note: learn to use `box-sizing: border-box`. In your fiddle all the `divs` that have `background-color` are `100% width` with it's parent. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: What's the difference? Sorry, I'm newbie of designing. And appreciated your note. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: BTW. All divs inside the div `wrapper` must extend out from it. sorrybad english. I mean, it should has the width that a `body` has, but the contents/texts must be fixed with `980px`.

Comment: If you can change your markup, then look at [@kapantzak answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27685154/1763929).

Comment: Yeah. That's what I really looking for. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ognceoaL/3/)

```
.div-inner {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing. But please explain further for me to understand and for future searcher. Thanks :D